# how to put the time labels of the timelineDay view of fullcalendar at the bottom?

Tags: html, jquery, css, fullcalendar

How to display the time label of the timelineDay view of the fullcalendar at the bottom ?
as you can see in this image below. the time is on top of the grid. I want it to be at the bottom of the grid. How do we do that? there's no article about it in the official documentation.

[image]

below is my code to display those things you see in the image above. I wonder what parameter or property do we need to add so that the time will appear at the bottom, not on top

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid','timeline'],
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth,listWeek'
  },
  defaultView: 'timelineDay',
  allDaySlot: false,
  slotLabelFormat: {
    hour: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
    minute: '2-digit',
    omitZeroMinute: true,
    meridiem: 'false'
  },
  showNonCurrentDates: true,
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
  drop: function(arg) {
    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if (document.getElementById('drop-remove').checked) {
      // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
      arg.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(arg.draggedEl);
    }
  }
});
calendar.render();
```

Note: am referring to the "HOURS" displayed,not the control buttons on top

Comment: There's no way to do this, unless you customise the source code of the view yourself. Personally I think it's clearer at the top, but you may have your own opinion on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a footer section and move it there from your header section. The footer takes the same exact values as a header and will display at the bottom of the calendar. For more info you should check out https://fullcalendar.io/docs/toolbar

Comment: Am not referring to the buttons nor the april 30,2020 date....am referring to the individual hour on top of the grid